# Looking for the best ways to clear a lot of dirt off the top of a lawn grown with Zoysia

Tags: lawn

This afternoon, I had an excavation on my lawn to replace a sewer pipe.  While they did the best they could, my lawn is still heavily covered with dirt from the initial dig.  What are the best ways to clear a 25 x25 foot square worth of lawn of the dirt that has been left across it. An attempt of raking it by hand got me nowhere after an hour's work.   Since its Zoysia, the root bed is so dense I can't simply shake it look into the ground below.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.